# Integrating external files with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've just started using AngularJs.
I need to use the SunCalc module to calculate sun positions for my app.
I have no idea on how to integrate the file to the app and how to access his different functions while respecting the AngularJs structure. Where to put the file? How to call a function? etc...

Here is a link so you can quickly see the structure of the SunCalc module and hopefully help me.
https://github.com/mourner/suncalc/blob/master/suncalc.js

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this library exposes global `SunCalc` object with bunch of methods, what you can do is simply wrap this lib into custom service.

```
app.factory('SunCalc', function() {
    return window.SunCalc;
});
```

Then you could use it like this in controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, SunCalc) {
    $scope.position = SunCalc.getTimes(new Date(), 52.3667, 4.9000);
});
```

In this case you can event add your own methods to this service without messing with original library.

Note, that technically you could use globally accessible `SunCalc` without creating one more service for this. However using services offers sertain advantages: you can rename it easily, it allows to facade original library API, using global variables error-prone, etc.

Also remember to include script tag before Angular script tag.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/rbATLGfGE2kx32tmEEoX?p=preview

Comment: Could not have asked for a better answer! Clear and complete. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, I have sincerely tried for several hours to implement this file: https://github.com/justin-john/node-timezone/blob/master/lib/timezone.js I have followed the same logic as for the SunCalc file, but I was unsuccessful in doing so... May I ask for your help once again? Thank you very much

Comment: This is nodejs lib. It will not work out of the box with angular, unless you are porting it. there are no https modules and querystring.